# Is there an easy way to see that ${1\over5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12} > 1$?

Tags: inequality, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, harmonic-numbers, number-comparison

The sum $$\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12}$$ is just a bit larger than $1$.  Is there some clever way to show this other than to add the fractions together by brute-force?  For example, is there some way to group terms together and say something like "These terms sum to more than $\frac{1}{3}$, these terms sum to more than $\frac{1}{2}$, and these terms sum to larger than $\frac{1}{6}$, so the whole thing sums to more than $1$"?

Comment: On my calculator the sum is $1.019877344$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, I know what the sum is.  I'm looking for a way to recognize that it is larger than 1 without actually adding all of the numbers together.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For positive, unequal $a$ and $b$:

$\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b=\dfrac{a+b}{ab}>\dfrac4{a+b}$

because $(a+b)^2>4ab$ (the difference between these is $(a-b)^2$).  So,

$\dfrac15+\dfrac17>\dfrac4{12}=\dfrac13$

$\dfrac19+\dfrac1{11}>\dfrac4{20}=\dfrac1{5}$

$\dfrac18+\dfrac1{12}>\dfrac4{20}=\dfrac1{5}$

When these inequalities are put into the given sum the claimed bound follows.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: You could mention that this is the inequality between harmonic and arithmetic mean: $\frac{2}{1/a+1/b} < \frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: @mweiss if this solution is what you are looking for, then I think it should be chosen as an answer.

Answer (score 19):

Since $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is convex we have:-

$\dfrac15+\dfrac16+\dfrac17>\dfrac36=\dfrac12$

$\dfrac18+\dfrac19+\dfrac1{10}+\dfrac1{11}+\dfrac1{12}>\dfrac5{10}=\dfrac12$

Comment: This is also great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

$\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{10}=\dfrac{3}{10}=\dfrac{6}{20}$

$\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{12}=\dfrac{3}{12}=\dfrac{5}{20}$

$\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{8}>\dfrac{2}{8}=\dfrac{5}{20}$

$\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}=\dfrac{20}{99}>\dfrac{4}{20}$

Answer (score 6):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12}=$$
$$=\frac{17}{60}+\frac{17}{66}+\frac{17}{70}+\frac{17}{72}\geq\frac{17\cdot4^2}{60+66+70+72}=\frac{68}{67}>1.$$

Comment: My analysis uses C-S with pairs of terms.  +1 for getting a bound actually greater than $1$.