# Showing that $\frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{19} + \cdots + \frac{1}{47} < 1$ without brute force calculation

Tags: inequality, fractions, harmonic-numbers, number-comparison

Consider the sum  $$S = \frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{19} + \cdots + \frac{1}{47}$$.  A brute-force calculation (okay, I just used Wolfram Alpha) shows that
$$ S = \frac{442017301628992345493}{442720643463713815200} < 1$$

My question is whether there is some way to recognize that this sum is less than 1 *without* brute-force methods.  For example, is there some way to pair or group the terms together so that one can say something like "These terms sum to less than 1/6, these terms sum to less than 1/6, etc., so the whole thing sums to less than 1"?

(Note: if this problem looks familiar, it may be because it is a companion to [Is there an easy way to see that ${1\over5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12} > 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514103/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-that-1-over5-frac16-frac17-frac).  However, in that problem, the goal was to show that a particular sum of unit fractions was *greater* than 1, and the answers there used the fact that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is convex to argue that certain combinations are *greater than* specific values.  It's unclear to me whether those strategies can be adapted to show that a combination is *less than* a target value.)

**Edited to add:** I guess I should clarify that anything requiring the calculation of a logarithm or using an approximate value of $e$ would fall, in my opinion, under the heading of "brute force".  I'm looking for things that can be done *without the use of a calculator*.

Comment: The difference from 1 is less than 1/629, so this does not look easy! In other words it is smaller than $\frac{1}{43}-\frac{1}{47}$

Comment: You should check one of the (excellent) answers you have received for this question, for example that of Julian Rosen. It is a good habit, 3 weeks later, to check answers when you see you will not have better ones. I have seen that you have approximately been checking only, say, a half of the answers to your questions, some of them rather old...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integer numbers $$n_k:=\biggl\lceil{10000\over k}\biggr\rceil\geq{10^4\over k}$$ are easy to calculate by hand for the thirty numbers $k\in[18\,..\,47]$. Since
$$\sum_{k=18}^{47}\>n_k=9999<10^4$$
we arrive at the desired estimate.

Answer (score 17):

Because $1/x$ is a convex function, there is an inequality $1/x\leq \int_{x-1/2}^{x+1/2} t^{-1}\,dt$. It follows that
$$
\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{19}+\ldots+\frac{1}{47}\leq \int_{17.5}^{47.5}\frac{dt}{t}=\ln\left(\frac{47.5}{17.5}\right).
$$
By hand, we can check that $2.715\cdot 17.5=47.5125>47.5$, so that $\frac{47.5}{17.5}<2.715<e$, and therefore
$$
\ln\left(\frac{47.5}{17.5}\right)<1.
$$

Comment: By [Euler's continued fraction for $e$](https://oeis.org/A003417),
$$
e > 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1}}}}
= \frac{19}{7} = \frac{95}{35} = \frac{47.5}{17.5}.
$$

Comment: Wow ! what an elegant answer.

Answer (score 6):

In [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324300?origin=crossref&seq=1), D.W. DeTemple established that the sequence

$$R_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}-\ln\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

is strictly decreasing and converges very fast toward the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$. Notice that the harmonic series

$$H_n = R_n + \ln\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

So

$$R_{47} < R_{17} \Rightarrow H_{47}-\ln\left(47+\frac{1}{2}\right) < H_{17}-\ln\left(17+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Therefore

$$H_{47} - H_{17} < \ln\left(\frac{95}{2}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{35}{2}\right) < 1$$

The last inequality is equivalent with $95 < 35e$, which is true and can be verified by hand if we approximate $e$ to three decimals.

Notice that the same approach does not work with the classic definition

$$\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n\right)$$

because $H_n - \ln n$ converges very slow toward $\gamma$.